# How to create multiple threads from an application and do not listen to their response?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to do the following :

I have a server that is supposed to get many messages from a queue and process them. Now what I want is to create a new thread for every message and those threads will handle the response to the queue, I just want my server (core thread) to be just listening to messages and creating threads, not caring of what happens to them.

How can I achieve this? I know I can use the `Thread` class to create a thread but then the application just keeps listening to the thread until if finishes.
Also I can create an `async` method and run it but what happens when it finishes? Also the method is supposed to be static if I want it to be `async` but in my current application that is not a solution since I use many non static variables into this method.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have very specific reason, I'd recommend using Tasks instead of Threads. 
Likely they'll run in background anyway, but they produce less CPU/memory overhead and (in my opinion) are easier to handle in case of exception,...

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => ProcessMessage(message));
```

Maybe take a look at [this introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with

> I know I can use the Thread class to create a thread but then the application just keeps listening to the thread until if finishes.

Just spawn the thread and let it run:

```
    { 
        Thread t = new Thread(Foo);
        t.Start();
    }

    public void Foo()
    { }
```

This won't make the main thread listen to the child thread, it just spawn them and continue working on following instructions.

BTW there are tons of  result on [how to create and run threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't like when others do it, here are simple examples of each way (asynchrnous/task-based), and you pick which one you like.

**Asynchronous Implementation**

```
int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        string data = SomeMethodThatReturnsTheNextDataFromQueue();
        ProcessDataAsync(data);
    }
}

async private void ProcessDataAsync(string msg)
{
    // The *await* keyword returns to caller and allows main thread to continue looping.
    bool result = await ParseDataAndSaveSomewhere(msg);
    return;
}
```

**Task-Based Implementation**

```
int main()
{
    while(true) 
    {  
        string data = SomeMethodThatReturnsTheNextDataFromQueue();
        Task task = new Task(() => { ProcessData(data) });
        task.Start();
    }
}

private void ProcessData(string data)
{
    // Do work
}
```